# Combine Spring REST service with Wicket

Tags: java, spring, rest, wicket

So I am developing a REST API in an application that uses both Spring and Wicket at the same time.

If I annotate @RequestMapping(value="/exchange") at my Spring @Controller annotated class (the one that is acting as a webserver), how do I have to configure Wicket to "recognize" http://myserver.com/myapp/exchange or http://myserver.com/myapp/exchange/onemethod as a valid URL so I don't get a 404 ERROR when I try to call the webservice from a client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JAX-RS [`@Path`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/Path.html) annotation:

```
@Path("exchange")
@Component
public class ExchangeService {

    @POST
    @Path("onemethod")
    public void oneMethod(...) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Comment: Ok, can you please tell me what should I import to use @Path annotation? Is it JAX-RS?

Comment: Yes, sorry I left that important detail out.  I've updated my answer.  You'll need to use a JAX-RS [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_RESTful_Web_Services#Implementations).  I'm a big fan of using [Jersey](https://jersey.java.net/).